How to delete azure VM and its associated resources like (ip, nsg, nic, disk) using REST API calls?
I have to delete Azure VM and associated resources using REST API calls.
I have sequential calls to delete Azure VM -> VM-Disk -> VM-Ip -> VM-NSG -> VM-Vnet
But after deleting VM, api call fails for Ip and NSG etc saying they are still in use.
Am wondering if I have to keep some buffer after which I should try.
Should I use some sort of Thread.Sleep for x time to delete NIC, IP etc after VM deletion ?

Kindly share the code that you have tried?

you should disassociate the network interface with NSG first.

Try to delete the VM first, and then delete other resources. I have deleted resources successfully using the REST API in PowerShell.

Here is the PowerShell Script to delete the resources using REST API CALL.

Note: Make sure to change the resource names with actual values.

I deleted a VM first, and then attempted to delete other resources. However, since other resources such as NICand VNET are associated to the VM, there were dependency issues.
    Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "SUB_ID"
    $Token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://management.azure.com/").Token
    
    # Array of REST API URLs to delete resources
    $urls = @(
        "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm?api-version=2024-03-01",
        "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/vm-os-disk?api-version=2023-10-02",
        "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/vm-nic?api-version=2023-09-01",
        "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/vm-public-ip-primary?api-version=2023-09-01",
        "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/vm-nic-nsg?api-version=2023-09-01",
        "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/network1?api-version=2023-09-01"
    )
    
    # Iterate through URLs and send DELETE requests
    foreach ($url in $urls) {
        try {
            $headers = @{
                Authorization = "Bearer $Token"
            }
            Invoke-RestMethod -Method Delete -Uri $url -Headers $headers
            Write-Host "Resource deleted successfully: $url"
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Failed to delete resource: $url. Status code: $_"
        }
    }

Output:
After executing the PowerShell script, resources has been deleted successfully.

